# Override range of ggplot to indicate the correct breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to set the limits and breaks for `ggplot()` with functions. I am able to do this, however, in some cases `ggplot()` overrides this and does not produce the correct output. Explicitly changing the number of breaks, works, however, this would be best if this was not required.

This does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame(x = c(302, 116, 10, 11),
                      y = letters[1:4])

ggplot(my_data,
       aes(x = x,
           y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) pretty(x),
                     limits = function(x) range(pretty(x)))
```

This works:

```
ggplot(my_data,
       aes(x = x,
           y = y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) pretty(x, 6),
                     limits = function(x) range(pretty(x, 6)))
```

The last seems unnecessary since the output of `pretty()` is the same in both instances:

```
pretty(my_data[['x']])
```

0  50 100 150 200 250 300 350

Or

```
pretty(my_data[['x']], 6)
```

0  50 100 150 200 250 300 350

Below the session information.

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.5.0      digest_0.6.27    withr_2.4.2      dplyr_1.0.7     
 [5] crayon_1.4.1     utf8_1.2.2       grid_4.1.1       R6_2.5.1        
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.0  gtable_0.3.0     magrittr_2.0.1   scales_1.1.1    
[13] pillar_1.6.2     rlang_0.4.11     farver_2.1.0     generics_0.1.0  
[17] vctrs_0.3.8      fortunes_1.5-4   ellipsis_0.3.2   tools_4.1.1     
[21] glue_1.4.2       purrr_0.3.4      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_4.1.1  
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_2.0-2 tidyselect_1.1.1 tibble_3.1.4
```

Comment: I use some functions from the package `scales` for this. Here some examples: `scales::label_number` and `scales::breaks_extended`

Comment: @ViníciusFélix, using ```scales::breaks_extended()``` gives a different output, however, it still does not produce the breaks to the limits. ```scales::breaks_pretty()``` is similar to the ```pretty()``` version.

Comment: @Ben, I have shown the output of of ```pretty()``` in the question. I get the same output, whether I use ```pretty(data$x)``` or ```pretty(data$x, 6)```. I want the plot to show the breaks as computed, however, without the additional ```n = 6```, this does not. I do not really want to manually adjust this. Since both ```pretty()``` versions gives the same output, I am unsure how to force ```ggplot()``` to use the first version.

Comment: @koortzjg It seems like `breaks = pretty` works fine, without indicating `n` - but when `limits` are added it loses the `breaks`...

Comment: @koortzjg I am able to reproduce the same problem...wonder if it's a bug?